# Hide IP with softether client in ubuntu - no response from DHCP

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, dhcp, softether

I have setup Softether VPN server on my OVH VPS with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-multi-protocol-vpn-server-using-softether). When I'm connecting from my windows machine everything works fine and the internet sees me by my VPN servers IP instead of mine. Now when I do the same in ubuntu, even though softether client shows that it's connected to the server, `curl ifconfig.me` returns the IP address of my machine instead of VPN. I've found info that on Linux I have to setup routing manually - and here problem arises. When I try to `sudo dhclient myadapter`, it just hangs there. Sometimes it will freeze forcing me to reboot, and sometimes I can kill it.
What I've seen in journalctl is:

```
can't create /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases: Permission denied
Open a socket for LPF: Operation not permitted
```

Is there something wrong with my dhclient? Or maybe there is any other way to configure the routing for it?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have this problem described in the [ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=807148). You might want to try the workaround suggested and try again:

```
I suggest the following:
touch /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclieht.eth0.leases
chown dhcp /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclieht.eth0.leases
```

Comment: For some reason there is no dhcp nor dhcpd user in my system

Comment: can you check the routing table inside the system and paste it here? command: ip route \

also probably you might need to add the default route pinting to the VPN gateway, https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/routing-tables

Comment: Since I was trying to setup the connection only for my CI/CD and I realised that it can be also achieved with openVPN client instead, so I took this route. I will probably come back to this as I'm curious how to do this, but right now I have too much work to have time to think about this. Thanks anyway